# Problems with Windscribe-CLI

Tags: command-line

I really couldn't find how to fix this problem anywhere.

I can't connect to any server of windscribe. Though I can do it from an application on windows 10 and extension of google chrome, but not from `windscribe-cli`. It says "Failed to connect" by trying to connect to 443/UDP.

I have added ports on firewall, I put SELinux to permissive, enforcing, disabled it as well. Nothing worked. I inactivate a proxy. By the way I have tested `windscribe-cli` from Ubuntu it works, but from CentOS it doesn't want to work at all.

Answer (score 2):

Use version 1.3 of `windscribe-cli` until this known issue is hopefully fixed in a newer release.

Version 1.4 does not work on Fedora, but it works on Ubuntu. After downgrading to 1.3, Windscribe connects on Fedora.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: Ohh wow this is still valid and works perfectly on fedora 34